# Замена компонента с помощью Mockito

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito

Писал тест для своего проекта на Spring Boot и появилась проблема: класс, который я тестирую, использует в одном из своих методов компонент CrudRepository (доступ на самом деле через сервис, но не столь важно). Суть в том, что так, как это тест, то при обращении к репозиторию возникает NullPointerException. Нужен способ подменить используемый компонент репозитория с помощью Mockito, чтобы была возможность самому установить возвращаемые им значения.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ответ. Если хотим подменить компонент Spring, в классе-тесте нужно внедрить этот компонент не через @Autowired, а через @MockBean.

Comment: Можно и через @Autowired, зависит от того где и как вы мокируете ваш crud repository.

Answer (score 0):

```
SaleRepository sRepo = mock(SaleRepository.class);
when(sRepo.findAllByEnabledFalse()).thenReturn(list);
```

Comment: SaleRepository в этом примере - это компонент, про который я говорил?